# Поиск слов целиком в тексте

Tags: javascript

Есть массив слов: `['дно', 'пог']`

Есть строка: `"видно погоду"`

Нужно проверить, если ли одно из слов массива в строке. Но именно слово целиком, а не как выше. Строгое вхождение. В строке могут быть смайлики и вообще любой текст и любые символы. Нужно как-то это всё отделить и проверить слова.

Как?

Comment: надо бы определиться, какие символы подряд образуют слово, а какие считаются уже не-словом. После этого регулярными выражениями задача решается.

Comment: А по-вашему `пог` - это целое слово?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да, это река.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Превращаешь слова в регулярное выражение (не забыв об экранировании спецсимволов) и добавляешь по краям `\b`. Дальше выполняешь проверку.

Поскольку js не понимает юникодные символы в управляющих последовательностях, начальное `\b` предлагаю заменить на `(?:^|(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\W)`, а конечное на `(?=(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\\W|$)` (и предпросмотр тут не случайно, но в этом вопросе не важно).

Получится примерно такая конструкция:

```
['дно', 'пог', "[({})]/"].map(s => RegExp("(?:^|(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\\W)(" + s.replace(/([\\\[\]])|./g, (ch,ecs) => "[" + (ecs ? "\\" : "") + ch + "]") + ")(?=(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\\W|$)")).some(r => r.test("видно погоду"))
```

Или, в ES5 версии:

```
['дно', 'пог', "[({})]/"].map(function(s) { return RegExp("(?:^|(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\\W)(" + s.replace(/([\\\[\]])|./g, function(ch,ecs) { return "[" + (ecs ? "\\" : "") + ch + "]" }) + ")(?=(?![а-яёАЯЁ])\\W|$)" )}).some(function(r) { return r.test("видно погоду") })
```

Но лямбды надо бы заменить нормальными функциями - не у всех FF или свежий хром.

Comment: Только есть одна проблема: \b в JS не работает для UNICODE, только для ASCII.

Comment: @dzhioev, не подумал.

Comment: @dzhioev, ответ обновлён.

Comment: @exec, ответ обновлён.

Comment: Это на чем написано?)

Comment: @exec, джаваскрипт, но ES6. FF и хром съедят прям так. А для более классического вида надо заменить конструкции `x => ...` на `function (x) { return ... }`.

Comment: @qwertiy у меня Node.JS

Comment: @qwertiy я использую вариант ниже, чем он плох?

Comment: @exec, желательно конкрентнее пояснять, какой именно. А плох он тем, что `words = ['дно', '[', 'видно', 'но', 'погоду'],` => `Uncaught SyntaxError`, и `words = ['дно', '.*', 'видно', 'но', 'погоду'],` => `Слово ".*" содержится в строке`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29801/discussion-between-exec-and-qwertiy).

Comment: @exec, переписал на ES5.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне для Node.JS v. 10) Там разве есть .some()?

Comment: @exec, [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - должен быть, но если нет, возьми по ссылке.

Comment: @Qwertiy как мне в этой конструкции записать в массив слова, которые были найдены?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var words = ['дно', 'пог', 'видно', 'но', 'погоду'],
    str = 'видно погоду',
    i = 0,
    re;
for( ; i < words.length; i++ ) {
    re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + words[i] + '(?=\\s|$)', 'g');
    console.log('Слово "' + words[i] + (re.test(str) ? '"' : '" не' ) + ' содержится в строке');
}
```

Comment: Экранировать символы кто будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Какие символы и где экранировать?

Comment: Смотря как. Если посимвольно пихать в квадратные скобки, то отдельно обработать обратный слеш и квадратные скобки. Если не пихать, то все управляющие.

Comment: У меня (в FF) ничего не показывает. Я просто не знаю JS, но неужели там нет аналога `strstr()` из Си? Если есть, то все тривиально. Ищем вхождение `words[i]` + проверка символов перед и после. Если хоть один из них буква, то не входит.

Comment: @avp, вывод в консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Если строка завернута в теги

```js
let str = '<p>дом домишко домище надомный домовой домоводство</p>'
let words = ['дом', 'домоводство']

for(let word of words) {
  const re = new RegExp(`(^|[^_0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ])${word}([^_0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]|$)`, 'g')
  str = str.replace(re, `$1<span>${word}</span>$2`)   
}

document.body.innerText = str
```

Answer (score -2):

как вариант

```
var a=['odin','dwa','tri','chetire'];
var str='fdfdfdf  f34334343 odin hghghg';

function wordDetector(w,test){
    if (!w.length) return undefined;
    if (typeof test !== 'string') return undefined;
    for (var i=0;i<w.length;i++){
        if (test.match(w[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(wordDetector(a,str));
```

Comment: Не верно. Даже на примере из вопроса не работает. Ну и экранированием и не пахнет.